# Instagram Integration in Android

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

We have a requirement for sharing content ( ex. text message, image/photo) from **development App** ( sample app )  to the **Social media app** ( ex. facebook, twitter, linkedin, instagram etc).

I don't get any  sufficient help / content available in case of integration and sharing text message from sample app to the instagram app.

Approach while integration is not to use `Intent`.

I would be thankful, if anyone has a solution for the same.

Comment: Try this link http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/instagram-integration-android-application-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also find the link "https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-instagram-oauth/tree/master/android-instagram-oauth/src/br/com/dina/oauth/instagram" but it cant having sharing text message approach using Instagram.

Comment: Why can't you use Intents? Intent is Android's standard way to share data between applications. This might also help : https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/

Answer (score 1):

use asne library for all social app integration : https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE
try this link